# Mounting a partition on the same drive as the live cd OS

Tags: ubuntu, debian, partition, live-cd, rescue-disk

I have looked all over the internet and I cannot find any insights into exactly what I am trying to do. I have a live cd of a flavor of debian that I am trying to install onto a hard drive for use as a rescue disk. The drive is partitioned with two partitions.

- First partition: Live (Rescue) OS.
- Second partition: NTFS storage. Must be accessible from Windows.

The use case for this set up is booting from the Live partition on a computer that I need to get data off. I will store the data that I need to get on the data partition which will later be accessed by Windows.

I am trying to fit this whole thing onto one external hard drive. The problem arises when I boot into the live partition I cannot mount the data partition at all. It always fails with `Permission Denied`.

I have confirmed that I am root and that it is not the drive itself. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason you cannot mount a partition on the same drive that the live OS is running on.

I don't know enough about live disks to figure it out. Any ideas?